# How to enforce XHTML5 interpretation of a Web document?

Tags: xml, html

Is there any way to inform a Web browser that a document is coded in XHTML5, i.e. XML serialisation of HTML5? This question is not as obvious as the first impression may suggest — a conforming XHTML5 header is identical to this used for XHTML 1.0 so my browser (Mozilla Firefox 18) treats XHTML5 as XHTML 1.0, thus complaining on everything which hadn't been available before XHTML5 arised.

According to [W3C HTML5 Candidate Recomendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), the DOCTYPE header is optional (and even wrong for a valid XML), the html namespace is exactly the same as for XHTML 1.0. So how do we know how to classify the code below? And how does the browser distinguish the two standards?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <title>A questioning document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        XHTML5 or XHTML 1.0 — that is the question...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does Firefox make these complaints? What exactly are the complaints?

Comment: There is no way to make `<iframe>` work correctly, i.e.make it possible to load a content to it with `<a>`'s `target` property. In-line frames are forbidden in XHTML 1.0 Strict, but allowed in HTML5, thus its XML serialisation - XHTML5. But Firefox can't distinguish XHTML5 from XHTML 1.0 (so I can't) and assumes Strict variant as default, thus discarding `<iframe>`.

Comment: `<iframes>` are supported in XHTML 1.0 Transitional. I suspect your problem is not that "Firefox has decided it is Strict and is ignoring iframes" but that "Firefox does not support iframes in XML mode". I recommend not using XHTML (at least client side). It is more trouble then it is worth.

Comment: That's right. I didn't know that `<iframe>`s are not supported at all in XML mode. I will have to switch back to HTML, unwillingly ;)

Comment: @Quentin - iframes *are* supported in Firefox's XML mode. See my answer.

Comment: "So how do we know how to classify the code below? And how does the browser distinguish the two standards?" It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<iframe>` in XHTML5 (i.e. XML mode) works fine in Firefox. But you need to identify the iframe with the `id` attribute, not the `name` attribute.

On the other hand, for IE9, you need to use the `name` attribute and not the `id` attribute.

Best then, is to use both, set to the same value.

See http://www.alohci.net/application/xhtml+xml/iframe-in-xml.htm.ashx for an example.

Comment: Truth. The `id` attribute is crucial and makes `<iframe>` work perfectly in Firefox's XML mode. It's a bit tricky because the absence of `id` doesn't trigger any error message – it just "disables" this convenient feature. Thank you for the answer and example!

Answer (score 0):

Please see these links about the future of XHTML and why you're possibly only seeing XHTML 1.0 validation supported:

http://www.w3.org/2009/06/xhtml-faq.html

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5